# How to create a street by street heat map with Google Maps?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, maps, gis, mapbox

**Background** I'm a bit new to google maps/mapping sdks in general. I want to create a street by street "heat" map of an area on iOS. As an easy to understand example, let's say it will be for the purpose of mapping daily puppy sighting in a city. The data changes regularly, we need to show that certain streets have more puppy traffic than others.

Similar to the ones pictured here
[image]
https://blog.mapbox.com/spotangels-mobile-parking-maps-30db4b10aee7

And here
[image]
https://www.trulia.com/local/san-francisco-ca/type:traffic_volume_live

I found plenty of information on creating heat maps and polylines, and snap to road vectors, but I can't find any documentation, tutorials, or examples about how to approach a problem like this.

**Question:** Assuming I have the daily data, how would I create the lines that show what streets/street segments have more puppies than others, similar to the maps above? A link to StackOverflow, Github, Google API Documentation, or blog would be greatly appreciated.

**Related side question**: What's the proper term for this kind of map/mapping methodology? It's not a heat map exactly or a choropleth?

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked the Google Maps SDK for iOS documentation for creating [polygons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/shapes#polygons) and [point-based heatmaps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility/heatmap)?

Comment: I have. It doesn't look like heat maps are the answer. They're more blubs. I'm looking for lines that correlate with the beginning/end of street corners. As for polygons, I don't know enough to say that's the right answer or not.

Comment: As soon as you have a a value representing each line, just draw polylines with different colors.  See also [d3 scales](http://d3indepth.com/scales/)